# Python: Change in Django model not recognised

Tags: python, django, shell, model

This must be really simple, but I can't get my head around it. 
I want to assign a simple one-character value to a django model instance. I have done that a million times, but in this case, it does notwork.

my models.py

```
class MetaInformation(models.Model):
    # part of the class profile ...
    PROFILE_STATUS = (
        ('C', 'Claimed'),
        ('U', 'Unclaimed'),)
    status = models.CharField(_('Profile'), max_length=1,
        choices = PROFILE_STATUS,)

class Profile(MetaInformation):
    # additional attributes
    ...
```

Now I am executing in the `Django shell`:

```
In [1]: a = Profile.objects.all()
In [2]: a[1].status
Out[2]: u'U'
In [3]: a[1].status = Profile.PROFILE_STATUS[0] # equal to 'C'
In [4]: a[1].save()
```

I would expect that the result is

```
In [14]: a[1].status
Out[14]: u'C'
```

but Django returns

```
In [14]: a[1].status
Out[14]: u'U'
```

**Why is the saving of the attribute not recognised or any error message provided?**

Comment: Doing `Profile.PROFILE_STATUS[0]` is not healthy. If you know the value is 'C', just set it to that and save. See if that works.

Comment: hi Bibhas, I have tried that as well, but the result is still `u'U'`. All my assignments are ignored.

Comment: What does your SupplierProfile model definition look like?

Comment: SupplierProfile was a typo. Besides that `Profile` is nothing special, I would say. Just the `Profile` inherits the status attribute from `MetaInformation`. Please see the updated model definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this -

```
>>> from apps.users.models import Member
>>> members = Member.objects.all()
>>> members[1].user_type
u'C'
>>> members[1].user_type = 'M'
>>> members[1].save()
>>> members[1].user_type
u'C'
>>> m = members[1]
>>> m.user_type
u'C'
>>> m.user_type = 'M'
>>> m.save()
>>> m.user_type
'M'
```

here is what I think is happening: The `all()` method returns a QuerySet. And from the queries above, the changes are not being committed to database when you execute `save()` on an item in the QuerySet. But it does work if you do it on a `Member` object individually. And from Django documentation -

> QuerySets are lazy -- the act of creating a QuerySet doesn't involve
>   any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
>   and Django won't actually run the query until the QuerySet is
>   evaluated. ...
>
> In general, the results of a QuerySet aren't fetched from the database
>   until you "ask" for them. When you do, the QuerySet is evaluated by
>   accessing the database.

You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). So the `save()` method on `members[1]` doesn't touch the database or read back from there. While the changes on the `Member` objects are committed to database and read back immediately.

Comment: Just referencing `members[1]`, though, will evaluate the queryset. From the page you linked to, slicing is one of the operations that causes Django to actually read from the database.

Comment: @IanClelland It seems like QuerySet only reads when evaluated. I'm not sure. Still digging.

Comment: yes, and indexing into it is one way of evaluating. It definitely hits the database, for one item. Look at the source for `QuerySet.__getitem__` to see exactly how it does it.

Answer (score 4):

Bibhas has most of the right answer, I believe. The fact that you are always referencing the data through a QuerySet, `Profile.objects.all()` is the the largest part of it. Couple that with the way that Django handles slicing (like list indexing, but a QuerySet isn't really a list), and the fact that databases don't have to consider records ordered, and you have a fantastic source of confusion and frustration.

The sequence

```
a = Profile.objects.all()
a[1].status
```

will produce SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_profile LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

in order to get the single value from the table. There are a couple of important things here:

1. Only one record is fetched. This is done for efficiency, since you only asked for a single record, there's no point in retrieving any more. This also means that
2. Django won't populate the QuerySet's cache. This means that the next time you ask for a[1], it will hit the database again.
3. There is no order specified on this query. The database is free to return the rows in whatever order is most efficient for it, and that order can even change between queries.

I know that MySQL, specifically, will often return records in the order in which they were most recently updated. So just by saving the record, it becomes unlikely to be in the same position as it was before. It may move to the start of the result set, or the end of it, but it is unlikely to remain in position 1 (the second item returned).

To avoid this, don't treat the queryset like a list. Don't perform operations directly on items that you have retrieved using slicing syntax. If you need to do that, then store them in a temporary variable, and perform all of the operations on that variable.

This small modification would have avoided all of the trouble:

```
>>> a = Profile.objects.all()
>>> b = a[1]
>>> b.status
'U'
>>> b.status = 'C'
>>> b.save()
>>> b.status
'C'
```

Alternatively, if you need to treat it like a list, then make it one. Making a list out of a QuerySet will completely evaluate it, and will store the entire result set in memory, where a[1] is guaranteed to be the same object every time you ask for it.

```
>>> a = list(Profile.objects.all()) # Warning -- may be huge if the Profile table is large
>>> a[1].status
'U'
>>> a[1].status = 'C'
>>> a[1].save()
>>> a[1].status
'C'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I did not expect that this simple problem goes that far to the root of Django database handling.

Comment: @neurix Django provides quite a bit of abstraction. Dig in whenever you can. You'll learn a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

`PROFILE_STATUS[0]` is going to return the `('C', 'Claimed')` and its a tuple. You need `PROFILE_STATUS[0][0]`:

```
a[1].status = Profile.PROFILE_STATUS[0][0]
```

Comment: The result is still `u'U'` if I set the value via `PROFILE_STATUS[0][0]` or `u'C'`. Everything I assign is simply ignored.

Comment: just for the sake of testing. Restart your shell and check again if value is still `U`

Comment: Same result: after a restart I get this result:
`In [1]: a = Profile.objects.all()
In [2]: a[1].status
Out[2]: u'U'
In [3]: a[1].status = 'C'
In [4]: a[1].save()
In [5]: a[1].status
Out[5]: u'U'`